# C++ AVLtree delete node and balance

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, tree, avl-tree

I'm trying to implement an AVL-Tree in C++.
So far the insertion and balancing the tree  works just fine.
The algorithm I'm trying to implement is:

step 1: delete / insert the wanted node just like in BST.

step 2: balance the tree from the same course of insertion/deletion.

I want to split it into two steps so It wont become  hard to read and program.
the problem is with step 2,
'insert' is working fine because I can just search the tree for the  existing node and then use recursion to update the course it went through.

but when deleting, because the node has already been deleted, I can't find the route which it went through in step 1.

I thought about inserting the successor but had no luck,
I'd really like to keep it with 2 steps even though all of the implementation I saw online combined both steps

Comment: "can just search the tree for the existing node" Don't do it this way. The insert function "knows" what it has just inserted, it should call the balance function *and pass it the subtree to balance as an argument*. Likewise, the delete function should call the balance function and pass it the subtree to balance as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

The following video are useful for understanding the rotations and insertion as well as deletion from AVL tree:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8JkBIA9V6Nc&list=PL30dC-5PIyXljRGbjvZ-mG8OITMESqxuj&index=12

Example:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LkwZggRs0t8&list=PL30dC-5PIyXljRGbjvZ-mG8OITMESqxuj&index=13